# How to create a node js function that always wait for new lines from java system.out.println?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I would like to seek ideas on how can i create a function that always wait for new lines due to delay from my java app via the stdout?

I want to display it to my terminal console in a manner where the data is presented progressively instead of as one whole chunk.

Here is my java codes:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        // System.out.println("Hello, Worldzzz");
        for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            } 
            System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my node js codes so far:

```
var http = require('http'),
    util = require('util'),
    url = require('url'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child,
    result = '',
    poort = 8088;

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });

    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    if (pathname == '/test') {
        res.write('test:');
        child = exec('java HelloWorld', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log = function(d) {
                process.stdout.write(d + stdout + '\n');
            };
            //console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
            console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

            if (error !== null) {
                console.log('exec error: ' + error);
            }
        })
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.write('operation not allowed');
        res.end();
    }

}).listen(poort);
```

Comment: Doesn't `.exec` already wait for your program to terminate before calling your callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `child_process.exec()` you will need to use `child_process.spawn()` and listen for events.

### Examples

Here is a simplified example that waits for the Java program to finish and prints everything in one big chunk:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('java HelloWorld', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  } else {
    process.stdout.write(stdout);
  }
});
```

Here is an example of Node program processing every line as soon as it's printed by the Java program:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('java', ['HelloWorld']);
child.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error('Error:', err);
});
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  process.stdout.write(data.toString());
});
```

Keep in mind that `data` is a buffer not a string - if you need a string you have to use `data.toString()` (here it would also work without the `.toString()` because `process.stdout.write()` can take buffers as arguments but I added it for clarity).

You may also need to listen for the close event so that you know when it's finished writing output:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('java', ['HelloWorld']);
child.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error('Error:', err);
});
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  process.stdout.write(data.toString());
});
child.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('Child exited with code', code);
});
```

See [the documentation of spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for more details.

Comment: @user66 It's good to know. I'm glad I could help. You can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so other people who search for that problem could know that it has been answered.